# Insert DATEDIFF Result into a column in table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query in SQL Server where it computes the difference between two dates, it's okay I get the result properly but I want that result to be stored in one of my columns in the Database. I can only work out how to display datediff but not how to store the result in a column.

```
select DATEDIFF (DAY,date_1,date_2) As date_test from tbl_datetest;
```

Comment: If it's in the same table, why not use a Computed Column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the result as INT.
The return type is an integer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Or you can persist the computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_datetest 
ADD 
  [date_test] AS DATEDIFF (DAY,date_1,date_2) PERSISTED
```

Comment: I have a existing column where the result will be stored.

Comment: Just add "PERSISTED" to the column definition. So the concrete column type is INT.

Comment: I have a existing column where i want the date to be store. it has a error like this since i have an existing column. "Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'date_result' in table 'tbl_datesample' is specified more than once."

Comment: you have read the error message? :) you have another column named date_result.

Comment: Yup, its okay now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET    yourcolumn = (SELECT Datediff (day, date_1, date_2) AS date_test 
                     FROM   tbl_datetest
                     WHERE  primarykey = avalue) 
WHERE  primarykey = avalue
```

This performs an update on desired table, overwriting your desired column with the return value of `DATEDIFF()`

However this works if you want to store the value in a different table, if you are keeping the value in the same table then you can have a computed column as @7schmiede suggested.

Comment: I got an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @Siegrain then you will need a where clause in the select statement, I forgot to add one as you didn't provide one your question. edited

Comment: You dont need a subquery to do this. But i would go for the computed column

Comment: @Thomas however as OP has stated it will be in a different column using a subquery just generates less confusion

Comment: Still no need for  a subquery. UPDATE table SET YOURCOLUMN = datediff(dd,date_1,_date2)

Comment: Thanks guys! Its okay now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Storing a value that can be derived from other fields is a [Transitive Depency design error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). As @Lamu said, a Computed Column is OK, otherwise, you can also put that calculation in a `view`.

Comment: A view would be the best approach, however if you need to store it in the table the Computed Column is possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it is only a confusion with the derived column naming with using `AS` in your query. because while updating a column value with the calculated column, you would not need to name it.

To update the column value in the same table where both date columns exist.

```
update tbl_datetest set <SameTableColumnName> = DATEDIFF (DAY,date_1,date_2) from tbl_datetest
```

To update the column value in the other table using both date columns of your current table

```
update <OtherTableName> set <OtherTableColumnName> = DATEDIFF (DAY,b.date_1,b.date_2) from tbl_datetest b
```

Use the `where` clause as you need in the same query.